# Google Apps Script Exceeded maximum execution time

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My code for an API pull has been timing out a lot lately. Here is my code (note that I have changed some variables for privacy):

```
// SHEET DATA
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
var view_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('views');
var num_rows = view_sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()

// API URL
var api_url = "url"
var api_url2 = "end of url"

// AUTH
var user = 'email'
var apikey = "apikey"
var token = user + "/token:" + apikey;
var encode = Utilities.base64Encode(token);
var params =
    {
      "method" : "get",
      "headers" :
      {
        "Content-type":"application/xml",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + encode
      }
    };

// calls the zendesk API for each view on the views tab, adds it's view count as a new row on the data sheet
function zdAPIcall() {

  // for date formatting
  var time = new Date();
  var time_utc = new Date(time.getUTCFullYear(), time.getUTCMonth(), time.getUTCDate(),  time.getUTCHours(), time.getUTCMinutes(), time.getUTCSeconds());

  // loops through views on views tab (excluding header row)
  for (i=2; i<=num_rows; i++) {

    // pulls the view ID
    var view_id = view_sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    // builds the API URL
    var full_api = api_url + view_id + api_url2;

    // finds the last row to add the value to
    var update_row = data_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    // hits the zendesk api
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(full_api,
                                     params);

    // pulls the response as json, extracts the view count value
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    var view_count = data['view_count']['value']

    // adds the data as a new row to the data sheet
    data_sheet.getRange(update_row,1).setValue(time_utc)
    data_sheet.getRange(update_row,2).setValue(view_id)
    data_sheet.getRange(update_row,3).setValue(view_count)
    Logger.log("row added!")

  };
};
```

Comment: This might be better off at [so].

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Does it include the line number? How do you call the `zdAPIcall` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better not to call `setValue` in a loop, but instead form a double array of values to be inserted, and put them all at once with `setValues`. This often helps with keeping resource use under quota.

However, in your case the main issue is not `setValue` but `UrlFetchApp.fetch` in a loop. Hitting some API a bunch of times in a loop is an expensive thing to do, both for your script and the API provider. The maximum execution time of Apps Script [is 6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), after which the script is terminated with the message you quoted. To avoid this, follow [Anton Soradoi's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608327):

> - Store the necessary information (i.e. like a loop counter) in a spreadsheet or another permanent store (i.e. ScriptProperties).
> - Have your script terminate every five minutes or so.
> - Set up a time driven trigger to run the script every five minutes(or create a trigger programmatically using the Script service).
> - On each run read the saved data from the permanent store you've used and continue to run the script from where it left off.

Terminating a script means recording the starting time `start = Date.now()`, and then checking in the loop whether you are running over 5 minutes (`start+5*60*1000`). If this happens, exit the loop (hence the script) but [set a  trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) to resume work in a few minutes. Since you already work with a spreadsheet and record the results there, it will not be difficult to find the place where the script should pick up the work after restart.